# R function for matrix differentatin

Tags: r, matrix, difference

I have a matrix with 90 vectors long 2048 records and I would like to differentiate each vector from 1:90 with each vector from 1:90.
The result will be a 90 matrix with 90 vectors contenining the result of each differentiate.

How can I do it?

my trial was this: matrix[1:90]-matrix[1:90], but the result was only 1 matrix with only 0, becouse there was a simply differentiation with the same matrix.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Are you saying that nrow for the matrix is 2048 and ncol as 90?  Also, it is not clear about the expected result.

Comment: Yes, nrow is 2048 and ncol is 90.

Comment: I would like to differ each col with each col, in order to make 90 diff for each col, and the total of diffs is 90*90

Comment: Suppose you have a 5 column matrix, I guess you want to take the difference of 1st column with 2:5 columns, 2nd column with all other columns except 2, right?

Comment: it's non easy, I know

Comment: My question is also that how do you want to combine the differences between the 1st column and all others except 1st (here, there will be 4 columns), similarly for 2nd (also 4) , 3rd etc.

Comment: Produce a small example of a matrix (we don't need 90 columns or 2048 rows) and show the expected result.

Comment: @user3459094 Suppose your matrix is `set.seed(15);m2 <- matrix(sample(1:20, 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)`, what will be the expected result

Comment: My results would be 90 new matrix with 90 columns conteining the difference value from the starting matrix between each columns. In the example with 5 col matrix I could be obtain new 5 matrix with, for each, 5 cols contains the diff between the i-st vector with the i-st to n-th vector.

Comment: @user3459094 It is not clear. Suppose I do `lapply(seq_len(ncol(m2)), function(i) m2[,i]-m2)`, it will be a list of 5 matrices with dimension 10 rows, 5 columns.

Comment: @akrun: my result with you example is new 5 matrix with, for each, five cols containing the diff result from the 1st col with the 1:5; more explicity: matrix 1 contains 5 cols with diff between 1st col to 1:5, the matrix 2 five cols with 2st to 1:5, matrix 3 five cols with the diff between 3st col with 1:5, matrix 4 five cols with the diff berween 4st col with 1:5, matix 5 five cols with the diff between 5st col with 1:5.

Comment: @user3459094 Have you run the code I posted before `lapply(..)`  If it is not the answer you are expecting, please show it in your post what will be your expected result.

Comment: akrun, I'm trying your code that would be correct! Give me some minuts and I'll answear to you if it works!

Comment: akrun, it runs! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lst <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(m1)), function(i) m1[,i]-m1)
length(lst)
#[1] 90
dim(lst[[1]])
#[1] 2048   90
```

Or

```
lst2 <- Map(`-`, as.data.frame(m1), list(m1))
length(lst2)
#[1] 90
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
 m1 <- matrix(sample(1:50, 90*2048, replace=TRUE), ncol=90)
```